# Fixing issues about angular routing module with multiple routes in angular 9

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular9

I have some issues in implementing multiple modules in angular 9. In my folder structure, I design my app like this

- core
- modules
- shared

In module folder, I have some other modules that they are imported into my app module.

In my app.routing module I defined my routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'question/:questionId', component: QuestionsComponent },
 { path: 'question', component: QuestionsListComponent },
 { path: 'news/:newsId', component: NewsComponent },
 { path: 'news', component: NewsListComponent },
 { path: 'justiceStockWatch', component: JusticeStockWatchlistListComponent },
 { path: 'broker', component: BrokerListComponent },
 { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
 { path: '**', component: Error404Component },
];
```

I have another module that it has some children. the name of the module is management module. the code below is for management module routing :

```
   const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path: 'management', component: ManagementComponent, children: [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'news', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'question', component: ManageQuestionsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'news', component: ManageNewsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'category', component: ManageCategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'subcategory', component: ManageSubcategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'justiceStockWatchlist', component: ManageJusticeStockWatchlistComponent, canActivate: 
        [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'broker', component: ManageBrokerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'login', component: ManagementLoginComponent },
   { path: 'register', component: ManagementRegisterComponent },
   { path: '**', component: ManagementError404Component }
       ]
   }
    ];
```

When I navigate through the main modules with links, there is no problem with the implementation. But as soon as I enter to the management module I am faced with wildcard route and get 404 error and navigate me to the 404 component that it is in the main module.

I have no idea that what I should do. In simple way, I want to manage child routes in each module when I have plenty of modules in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found a solution for me. The module with `**` route should be imported after all other modules with routing.

For instance, you have `MainModule` with `MainRoutingModule` and `SomeAnotherModule` with routing (`PagesModule`). `MainRoutingModule` includes the definition for `**` route with `NotFoundPage`. So you should import `PagesModule` and `MainRoutingModule` after them.

```
/// ... imports

@NgModule({
  declaration: [...],
  imports: [
    // ...
    PagesModule,
    MainRoutingModule
    // ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class MainModule {}
```